# How to call separate+ plugin in the gimp python plugin code?

Tags: python, gimp

I'm a newbie trying to write a small plugin for `gimp` using Python. It would generate an image and convert it to CMYK using the [separate+ plugin](http://www.vuiis.vanderbilt.edu/~welcheb/mac%20installs/GIMP/separate-0.3_macosx/separate.c)

Code sample:

```
# some code that creates xcf image
layer = pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(newimage, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
layer = pdb.plug_in_separate_light(some args here )
```

I have no idea how to call `pdb.plug_in_separate_light()` and then save the result image. I just know that `pdb.plug_in_separate_light()` requires 10 arguments and one of them should be a gimp drawable object(layer in my case) and two strings containing paths to icm/icc profiles. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found solution by myself.
pdb.plug_in_separate_light.params # this code returns set of sets with description of expected params